# How can I calculate the subtotal for filtered cells that meet certain criteria?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to create a subtotal for a range that excludes rows that don't have a wholesale price. I have a range of products, prices and units that have subtotals by brand, although the brand subtotal is a `sum` and not a `subtotal` because the total needs to be displayed regardless of what the user chooses to filter. These subtotal rows do not have wholesale prices.

Here is the sumif formula I'm using to calculate totals in the summary area above the range:

```
=SUMIF(B5:B12, "", D5:D12)
```

I need to have a subtotal formula that works the same way. Is there an equivalent to the sumif formula for subtotals? Or maybe a worksheet function I can use?

I need to be able to do this without using VBA.

[image: Incorrect Subtotals]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do conditional subtotals without VBA. Try this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(units,ROW(units)-ROW(D4),0,1)),--(wholesale=""))
```

**Where**
`units` refers to `D4:D12` in your screenshot, with `D4` as the header
`wholesale` refers to `B4:B12` in your screenshot

**Example** - The formula at work in cell D2:

[image]

Comment: Perfect! I hope you get lots of blueberry cheesecake today. Glad I could help with the Excel and problem solving part.

Comment: Np! And welcome to Superuser! :)

Comment: +1 - you could also use SUBTOTAL with 9 instead of 3 then you don't have to include units at the end of the SUMPRODUCT......

Comment: @barryhoudini Facepalmed myself there. Nice catch. :D

Comment: Found a similar solution many times all over the Internet, but this one is the only one that at least partially explains what is going on in the formula by assigning names to the ranges.